# Wrapping InteractiveViewer in GestureDetector causes InteractiveViewer input to respond poorly

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a gesture detector and wrapped it around a interactive viewer. But when I do, panning and scaling no longer work on my InteractiveViewer. Or atleast it responds very poorly to input.

This is my GestureDetector

```
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().rewind(),
      onVerticalDragStart: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().rewind(),
      onHorizontalDragStart: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().rewind(),
      onTapUp: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().resume(),
      onVerticalDragEnd: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().resume(),
      onHorizontalDragEnd: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().resume(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The InteractiveViewer will respond poorly to input. I tried setting this

```
behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild
```

and

```
behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent
```

But it does not work

How can I fix this?

Also with the gesture detector I am trying to detect a tap anywhere on the page whil the interactive viewer only is a small part of the page.

Side Note: Just is just some example code the to illustrate the widget structure. In reality the container is not just blue and the Interactive Viewer is nested deeper.

Comment: You may try the gesture_x_detector package, it handles all of them.

Comment: Well in reality the InteractiveViewer is nested way deeper. This is just to show what the structure is like.

Comment: By using `GestureDetector` you're trying to catch when user drags on `InteractiveViewer`?

Comment: Well I am trying to detect if the user taps anywhere on the page so I can pause a tutorial. The InteractiveViewer is only a small part of the page

Comment: I updated the code to better illustrate what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Listener` if you just want to get notified when user starts and stops touching things under it. With `GestureDetector` there is no way you can catch gestures and also send it to `InteractiveViewer` being it's child. Here is an example:

```
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (_) {
    // rewind
  },
  onPointerCancel: (_) {
    // resume
  },
  onPointerUp: (_) {
    // resume
  },
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

check this you might not able to see the container moving or scaling but when you put something bigger than screen sizes like an image or something `InteractiveViewer` will kick into work below example could help but the exact problem you want to fix might help with basics. Replace container with `SizedBox` to work properly

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

    void main() async {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(),
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          home: Provider(
            create: (context) => TutorialBloc(),
            child: MyPage(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().rewind(),
          onVerticalDragStart: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().rewind(),
          onHorizontalDragStart: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().rewind(),
          onTapUp: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().resume(),
          onVerticalDragEnd: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().resume(),
          onHorizontalDragEnd: (_) => context.read<TutorialBloc>().resume(),
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: InteractiveViewer(
                  child: Image.network(
                      'https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/500/442/354/outrun-vaporwave-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class TutorialBloc {
      void rewind() {
        debugPrint('rewind');
      }

      void resume() {
        debugPrint('resume');
      }
    }
```